# 「今話題のメタ投稿」が更新されていない

Tags: バグ

「今話題のメタ投稿」が更新されていません。

本来、更新されるはずだと考える理由:

- もっと票や回答を集めている投稿が有るのに追加されていない
- 現在表示されている投稿はプラス3票入った時点（9月21日）から表示されているが、10日以上継続されているのが不自然

10月3日時点のスクリーンショット:

> [image: 10月3日時点の「今話題のメタ投稿」]

Comment: こちらの"Hot Meta Post"に関するMSE の投稿をご参照くださいませ: [What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621/335251)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10月5日〜6日あたりにスコア +3 になった別の投稿に置き換わりました。（それ以前に +3 以上になった投稿は他にも有ったので、動きが不可解ではありますが）